# Create a new wallet on public node

Tags: wallet, cardano-node

I want to create a wallet and use it but I don’t want to run a node locally. I recently found Blockfrost but, I don’t think it has the option to create a wallet. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

You can always use [Yoroi](https://yoroi-wallet.com/#/), which is just a browser extension that connects to trusted remote nodes to interface with the chain.

Additionally, if you want to create a wallet in a completely cold, network-isolated fashion, you can use cardano-cli (and/or cardano-wallet) on an airgapped machine.

[Section 10](https://www.coincashew.com/coins/overview-ada/guide-how-to-build-a-haskell-stakepool-node#10.-setup-payment-and-stake-keys) of Coincashew's SPO guide has a neat bash script for creating mnemonic wallets in an airgapped environment. Perhaps it may be of help in your python script!

Comment: I'm writing a python script so I don't think a browser extension helps me a lot.

Comment: edited to include a sample bash script

Comment: Thanks, That was helpful! But Isn't there any public node like Blockforest to give that service?

Comment: Wallet/Key generation is an entirely offline process. Even if there was a public entity that offers such a service, it kind of defeats the purpose of generating keys in a secure/cold fashion.

Comment: Thanks man. That was helpful.